# How to display multiple values in a textView

Tags: java, android

I can't get String Builder to work properly for me, I know the values generated work but only the last one is added into the textView.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    Intent newGame = getIntent();
    int temp = newGame.getIntExtra("int_value", 0); // here 0 is the default value

    Random r = new Random();
    int Low = 1;
    int High = 4;
    int Result = r.nextInt(High-Low) +Low;

    int[] numbers = new int [1];
    for(int Generated = 0; Generated < numbers.length; Generated++) {
        numbers[Generated] = (int)(Math.random() +temp);
    }
    int value;
    for (int rolls = 0; rolls < 4 +temp; rolls++) {
        value = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);
        //Test if numbers generated are correct
        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(value + " ");
            textView.setText(builder.toString());


            // Set the text view as the activity layout
            setContentView(textView);
            //store generated numbers here
            System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

In System.out.println(value); I can see the numbers generated but the textView only shows the last one.

Comment: `StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();` in looping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try edit like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int rolls = 0; rolls < 4 +temp; rolls++) {
    value = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    //Test if numbers generated are correct
    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    builder.append(value + " ");
    textView.setText(builder.toString());

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
    //store generated numbers here
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Comment: Move `setContentView(textView);` line outside `for-loop`

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want to do is use the StringBuilder to build up your string in the loop. Then set the value of the StringBuilder to the textView after the loop. Like this_:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int rolls = 0; rolls < 4 +temp; rolls++) {
    value = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    builder.append(value + " ");
    System.out.println(value);
}

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(builder.toString());

// Set the text view as the activity layout
setContentView(textView);
```

Comment: Thanks I got it, I have another question related to the same file. How can I store the generated values in an integer array?

Comment: Declare a integer array outside the for-loop and set array(rolls) = value inside the loop after value = (int) (Math.random() * 4 + 1);

Comment: Thanks, but could you show me a bit of code on how to achieve it? It all sounds pretty confusing to me

Comment: because when I try to do it the array displays as [I@22a00a57 and I dont know how to fix it

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the list? The [I@22a00a57 looks like the result of System.out.println(array)?

Comment: If you just want to print the items in the array you can do this in a loop like this: 
`for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
    system.out.println(array(i));
}
`

Comment: I just want to make sure that the numbers in the array are the same as the ones coming up in textView. I need to store them and do a check later if textView numbers and array numbers match